# Upload/Download data directly to Sql Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I'm working on a server/client application, in which the client has the ability to upload/download a file, which will be stored in SQL server (2012) as varbinay(max). The problem is that I want that the file will be uploaded directly to the database without saving the file on the server's hard drive, using ReadAllBytes method, which only accepts a path parameter.

Here is a fragment of the code used in the server side:

```
HttpPostedFile file1 = context.Request.Files[0];
            byte[] buffer = new byte[file1.ContentLength];
            file1.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, file1.ContentLength);
```

Here is the code user in order to write into a file from data in the database:

```cs
foreach (var file in list)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path + file.FileName, file.FileContents);
}
```

Comment: So... don't use ReadAllBytes?

Comment: What should i use then ?

Comment: Unrelated, but did you look at the `filestream` data type instead of `varbinary(max)`?

Comment: So what should i use to store the files in the database (type of the column)?

Comment: Don't use methods from the `File` class at all if you don't want to write to the disk. Wasn't the whole point to avoid using the disk directly?

Comment: Thanks for the answer & Happy New Year ! What you are saying make sense ! What do you suggest me to use then ?

Comment: You have a byte[] and that is what a varbinary expects.

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpPostedFile` comes with an input stream you can read from. Read it into a byte array, then store it in the database. Or if your database interface (in the case of EF this is unlikely) directly accepts a stream, just put it in as-is,

Do note that ASP.NET (or was it IIS?) may store a file upload temporarily on disk anyways, if it's very large.

Comment: Thaks for the quick answer, i'm taking a look at it !

Comment: the problem is that when i try to read files from the server, they are corrupted. but only simple text files work !

Comment: @kad_87 Then maybe you should show some code and describe what your real problem is.